# Importar una imagen de otra librería en openCV

Tags: python, opencv

Necesito ir pixel por pixel en una librería que genera imágenes de partituras (Python, Jupyter). De forma nativa estas librerías no tienen la opción.

¿Se puede hacer desde OpenCV?
el método `.imread` no reconoce las imágenes que generan las librerías.

Las librerías tienen un método `.show()` pero ningún método para barrer la imagen.

Comment: `imread()` recibe como parámetro la ruta de la imagen

Comment: Claro, el problema es que estas imágenes no se guardan en la computadora, se proyectan en Jupyter y listo. ¿Será que necesito guardarlas? Creo que sólo genera .png

Comment: Pues sip, guárdalas y ya, no importa el tipo de imagen opencv lo leerá igual

Comment: En la [documentación](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) te dice que acepta como parametros